# Dynamic database connection to mongodb or mongoose from nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to create a multi-tenant app (saas), where each client has its own database.

My situation is:

I created a middleware that would determine who the client is based on a subdomain, then retrieve the client's database connection info from a general database. I don't know how to establish a connection object for this client so as to be able to use in my controllers. And should I do this in the middleware  or in a controller? And if it's in the model, how do i pass the connection string and parameters (I could use session, but I don't know how to access session from within model).

How do i do the following?

1. Organisation: where do I create the db connection for client dynamically?
2. Inject/pass connection parameters to controller or model (where connection definition is made)
3. After dynamic connection has been made, how do i access it globally for that client?

This is an example of my middleware, and i would like to create a mongoose connection which i would like to make dynamic (pass in client's connection info):

```
function clientlistener() {
    return function (req, res, next) {
       console.dir('look at my sub domain  ' + req.subdomains[0]);
       // console.log(req.session.Client.name);

    if (req.session.Client && req.session.Client.name === req.subdomains[0]) {
          var options = session.Client.options;
          var url = session.Client.url
          var conn = mongoose.createConnection(url, options);
          next();
       }
    }
}
```

How do I access this connection object from inside the controller? Or from the model?

Thank you.

Comment: This is covered somwhat in the [documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#index_Mongoose-createConnection) Best to read that and then possibly "re-phrase" to usage of that to manage if you still do not understand.

Comment: I have been stuck on the document for ages. I understand document, my problem is where do I implement it? if i did it in my middleware, how do i make the connection object available in my controller or model ? and if i did it in my model, how do i pass in the dynamic (variable ore session) parameters ?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a good way to do this?  I am also struggling with it.

Comment: @Drastick yes I did.  It works pretty well,  I'm not sure if it is the professional way of doing it though. Please gimme a couple hours and I will paste an example with explanations

Comment: @mojotaker have you by chance had time to put that together?

Comment: @Drastick have not heard back from you,  was I helpful?

Comment: Sorry, yes it was very helpful. I did things a little differently because Im basing the database it uses on a config passed in after authentication. But other than that it works well for what I need.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is to help others who may find themselves in similar situation as I did. I hope that it could be standardized. I dont think we should have to reinvent the wheel every time someone needs to make a multi-tenant application.

This example describes a multi-tenant structure with each client having its own database.
Like i said there might be a better way of doing this, but because i didn't get help myself, this was my solution.

So here are the goals this solution targets:

- each client is identified by subdomain e.g client1.application.com,
- application checks if subdomain is valid,
- application looks up and obtains connection information (database url, credentials, etc) from master database,
- application connects to client database ( pretty much hands over to client),
- application takes measures to ensure integrity and  resource management (e.g use the same database connection for members of the same client, rather than make new connection).

### Here is the code

in your `app.js` file

```
app.use(clientListener()); // checks and identify valid clients
app.use(setclientdb());// sets db for valid clients
```

I've created two middlewares :

- `clientListener` - to identify the client connecting,
- `setclientdb` - gets client details from Master database, after client is identified, and then establishes connection to client database.

#### clientListener middleware

I check who the client is by checking the subdomain from the request object. I do a bunch of checks to be sure the client is valid (I know the code is messy, and can be made cleaner). After ensuring the client is valid, I store the clients info in session. I also check that if the clients info is already stored in session, there is no need to query the database again. We just need to make sure that the request subdomain, matches that which is already stored in session.

```
var Clients = require('../models/clients');
var basedomain = dbConfig.baseDomain;
var allowedSubs = {'admin':true, 'www':true };
allowedSubs[basedomain] = true;
function clientlistener() {
return function(req, res, next) {
    //console.dir('look at my sub domain  ' + req.subdomains[0]);
    // console.log(req.session.Client.name);

    if( req.subdomains[0] in allowedSubs ||  typeof req.subdomains[0] === 'undefined' || req.session.Client && req.session.Client.name === req.subdomains[0] ){
        //console.dir('look at the sub domain  ' + req.subdomains[0]);
        //console.dir('testing Session ' + req.session.Client);
        console.log('did not search database for '+ req.subdomains[0]);
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(req.session.Client, null, 4));
        next();
    }
    else{

        Clients.findOne({subdomain: req.subdomains[0]}, function (err, client) {
            if(!err){
                if(!client){
                    //res.send(client);
                    res.send(403, 'Sorry! you cant see that.');
                }
                else{
                    console.log('searched database for '+ req.subdomains[0]);
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(client, null, 4));
                    //console.log(client);
                   // req.session.tester = "moyo cow";
                    req.session.Client = client;
                    return next();

                }
            }
            else{
                console.log(err);
                return next(err)
            }

        });
    }

   }
 }

module.exports = clientlistener;
```

#### setclientdb middleware:

I check everything again making sure that the client is valid. Then the connection to the client's database with the info retrieved from session is opened.

I also make sure to store all active connections into a global object, so as to prevent new connections to the database upon each request(we don't want to overload each clients mongodb server with connections).

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
//var dynamicConnection = require('../models/dynamicMongoose');
function setclientdb() {
    return function(req, res, next){
        //check if client has an existing db connection                                                               /*** Check if client db is connected and pooled *****/
    if(/*typeof global.App.clientdbconn === 'undefined' && */ typeof(req.session.Client) !== 'undefined' && global.App.clients[req.session.Client.name] !== req.subdomains[0])
    {
        //check if client session, matches current client if it matches, establish new connection for client
        if(req.session.Client && req.session.Client.name === req.subdomains[0] )
        {
            console.log('setting db for client ' + req.subdomains[0]+ ' and '+ req.session.Client.dbUrl);
            client = mongoose.createConnection(req.session.Client.dbUrl /*, dbconfigoptions*/);


            client.on('connected', function () {
                console.log('Mongoose default connection open to  ' + req.session.Client.name);
            });
            // When the connection is disconnected
            client.on('disconnected', function () {
                console.log('Mongoose '+ req.session.Client.name +' connection disconnected');
            });

            // If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection
            process.on('SIGINT', function() {
                client.close(function () {
                    console.log(req.session.Client.name +' connection disconnected through app termination');
                    process.exit(0);
                });
            });

            //If pool has not been created, create it and Add new connection to the pool and set it as active connection

            if(typeof(global.App.clients) === 'undefined' || typeof(global.App.clients[req.session.Client.name]) === 'undefined' && typeof(global.App.clientdbconn[req.session.Client.name]) === 'undefined')
            {
                clientname = req.session.Client.name;
                global.App.clients[clientname] = req.session.Client.name;// Store name of client in the global clients array
                activedb = global.App.clientdbconn[clientname] = client; //Store connection in the global connection array
                console.log('I am now in the list of active clients  ' + global.App.clients[clientname]);
            }
            global.App.activdb = activedb;
            console.log('client connection established, and saved ' + req.session.Client.name);
            next();
        }
        //if current client, does not match session client, then do not establish connection
        else
        {
            delete req.session.Client;
            client = false;
            next();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if(typeof(req.session.Client) === 'undefined')
        {
           next();
        }
        //if client already has a connection make it active
        else{
            global.App.activdb = global.App.clientdbconn[req.session.Client.name];
            console.log('did not make new connection for ' + req.session.Client.name);
            return next();
        }

    }
    }
}

module.exports = setclientdb;
```

### Last but not the least

Since I am using a combination of mongoose and native mongo, We have to compile our models at run time. Please see below

Add this to your `app.js`

```
// require your models directory
var models = require('./models');

// Create models using mongoose connection for use in controllers
app.use(function db(req, res, next) {
    req.db = {
        User: global.App.activdb.model('User', models.agency_user, 'users')
        //Post: global.App.activdb.model('Post', models.Post, 'posts')
    };
    return next();
});
```

Explanation:

Like I said earlier on I created a global object to store the active database connection object: `global.App.activdb`

Then I use this connection object to create (compile) mongoose model, after i store it in the db property of the req object: `req.db`. I do this so that i can access my models in my controller like this for example.

Example of my Users controller:

```
exports.list = function (req, res) {
    req.db.User.find(function (err, users) {

        res.send("respond with a resource" + users + 'and connections  ' + JSON.stringify(global.App.clients, null, 4));
        console.log('Worker ' + cluster.worker.id + ' running!');
    });

};
```

I will come back and clean this up eventually. If anyone wants to help me, that be nice.

Comment: in similar situation. trying this approach. give code looks very helpful. thanks for detailed explanation.

Comment: I recently refactored the code above.  Let me know if you need help,  or give you an updated version

Comment: I ment "given* code looks very helpful".. thanks for responding. i am trying something little different. i.e. instead of compiling model in controller caching them and reusing them when needed. This post is my day savior :).

Comment: mojotaker could you contact me? I'm in the same situation and trying to use your code. Is this already the refactored example?

Comment: @wegginho hello,  I will respond to you,  in a bit.  I have done 2 different refactorings since this.  But what exactly is your problem?

Comment: @wegginho as per the code above,  it's been cleaned up thanks (can see his name to give credit)

Comment: How and where do you store sessions?

Comment: @wegginho Ok,  to clarify some things,  the how:  is in the code above,  in the clientlistener middleware. After I check if the client is valid,  by searching the master db, I then store it in session.  The why : session persists  through requests,  and if it times out,  or expires,  client has to revalidate itself.

Comment: @wegginho Clients.findOne({subdomain: req.subdomains[0]}, function (err, client) {
            if(!err){
                if(!client){
                    //res.send(client);
                    res.send(403, 'Sorry! you cant see that.');
                }
                else{
                    console.log('searched database for '+ req.subdomains[0]);
                    //console.log(JSON.stringify(client, null, 4));
                    req.session.Client = client;
                    return next();

                }

Comment: @wegginho in node js,  session is just storage made available on the request.session object /variable.

Comment: Ok, but in express you have to define express-session somewhere to have the session object available. I tried to use express-session in mongostore with what you provided, which is a dilemma because I don't know the right database when I'm initializing the session.

The Order would be:
- check subdomain
- set default database
- initialize session (with mongostore)
- set session's default database

correct?

Comment: @wegginho, can you please contact me, send me an email allotofjunk@gmail.com, and i will be glad to help you to the best of my ability.

Comment: wrote the mail 3 days ago :(

Comment: @mojotaker On 7/16 you said you have done 2 different refactors since what is posted.  Would it be possible for you to post your most recent refactor?

Comment: @Drastick Ok i will try to soon.

Comment: @Drastic update posted, I will come back to explain and clean later.

Comment: @mojotaker Thanks for the explanations. I'm trying to do the same exact thing. Have you found any performance problems with maintaining many connections inside of the Node app? Also are you able to post your latest refactors? I would love to see what you ended up with.

Comment: The year is 2018. Still haven't seen a better solution.
I am, however, wondering if this has performance issues when working with dozens of databases.

Comment: The year is 2020. Looking for a better solution there. Performance is the main concern there.

Comment: @Yuanpeng.Zheng look at the other answer setclientdb.js It deals with some of the performance issue. I will come back over the weekend and clean this up. In the meantime, what are your concerns ?

Comment: @mojotaker, Thanks for prompt response. My concern is if the solution could handle over 20 connections (1k users) simultaneously, as putting connection in the middleware seems to be a lot of context switch there. Our backend also used socketIO, and integrated with other third party system with REST API calls as well. I may give it a go and let you know how it goes.

Comment: We don't use session, but jwt for authentication. So may not use req.session but req.user  and decoded to check validation there.

Comment: Is there a way to leverage the use of the function `useDb` In mongoose in order to create a new connection?

Comment: @mojotaker, thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I am for the first time implementing multi-tenant MEAN app, and would like to seek your advise on some of the topics like handling mongoose connections & models, guidelines for performance handling on handling number of tenants(dbs) and total number of users. would it be okay to contact you on email?

Comment: @Yuanpeng.Zheng, I am also using jwt and will be using req.user to validate a user and identify db name. And likely to have 1000 users. Any further feedback on this implementation from your side would be highly helpful.

Answer (score 10):

### Hello everyone, here is a much more updated solution.

So here are the goals this solution targets:

- each client is identified by subdomain e.g client1.application.com,
- application checks if subdomain is valid,
- application looks up and obtains connection information (database url, credentials, etc) from master database,
- application connects to client database ( pretty much hands over to client),
- application takes measures to ensure integrity and resource management (e.g use the same database connection for members of the same client, rather than make new connection).

### updates

- use of promises,
- automatic import & compilation of models
- New middleware ; modelsinit (used to automatically import and compile mongoose models)
- Clean up of middlewares (setclientdb, clientlistener, modelsInit)

### Please see below for some Explanations

**

### modelsInit Middleware

**
features

- tests if models are already compiled. If so, skip.
- tests to see if request is not a tenant request; i.e (request to apps homepage, admin page, etc)

  ```
  'use strict';
  /**
   * Created by moyofalaye on 3/17/14.
   */

  var path = require('path');
  var config = require('../../config/config');

  // Globbing model files

  config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/models/*.js').forEach(function (modelPath) {
      require(path.resolve(modelPath));

  });



  function modelsInit() {
      return function (req, res, next) {

  //console.log(req.subdomains[0]);
          switch (req.subdomains[0]) {
              case 'www':
              case undefined:
                  return next();
                  break;
              case 'admin':
                  return next();
                  break;
  //            default:
  //              return
          }
          var clientname = req.session.Client.name;

      // test if models are not already compiled if so, skip
      if (/*typeof req.db === 'undefined' && */ typeof global.App.clientModel[clientname] === 'undefined') {
          req.db = {};
       //Get files from models directory
              config.getGlobbedFiles('./app/models/clientmodels/**/*.js').forEach(function (modelPath) {
              console.log('the filepath is ' + modelPath);
              //Deduce/ extrapulate model names from the file names
              //Im not very good with regxp but this is what i had to do, to get the names from the filename e.g users.server.models.js (this is my naming convention, so as not to get confused with server side models and client side models

              var filename = modelPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');
              var fullname = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.'));
              var endname = fullname.indexOf('.');
              var name = fullname.substr(0, endname);
              req.db[name] = require(path.resolve(modelPath))(global.App.activdb);
              console.log('the filename is ' + name);
          });

          global.App.clientModel[clientname] = req.db;

          console.log(global.App.clients);

          return next();
      }
      // since models exist, pass it to request.db for easy consumption in controllers
      req.db = global.App.clientModel[clientname];
      return next();
      };
  }

  module.exports = modelsInit;
  ```

Todo: Further Explanation

### ClientListener.js

```
var config = require('../../config/config');
var Clients = require('../models/clients');
var basedomain = config.baseDomain;
var allowedSubs = {'admin': true, 'www': true};
allowedSubs[basedomain] = true;

//console.dir(allowedSubs);

function clientlistener() {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        //check if client has already been recognized
        if (req.subdomains[0] in allowedSubs || typeof req.subdomains[0] == 'undefined' || req.session.Client && req.session.Client.name === req.subdomains[0]) {
            console.log('did not search database for ' + req.subdomains[0]);
            //console.log(JSON.stringify(req.session.Client, null, 4));
            return next();
        }

        //look for client in database
        else {

            Clients.findOne({subdomain: req.subdomains[0]}, function (err, client) {
                if (!err) {
                    //if client not found
                    if (!client) {
                        //res.send(client);
                        res.status(403).send('Sorry! you cant see that.');
                        console.log(client);
                    }
                    // client found, create session and add client
                    else {
                        console.log('searched database for ' + req.subdomains[0]);
                        req.session.Client = client;
                        return next();
                    }
                }
                else {
                    console.log(err);
                    return next(err)
                }

            });
        }

    }
}

module.exports = clientlistener;
```

### setclientdb.js

```
var client;
var clientname;
var activedb;

var Promise = require("bluebird");
Promise.promisifyAll(require("mongoose"));
//mongoose = require('mongoose');


function setclientdb() {
    return function (req, res, next) {
        //check if client is not valid
        if (typeof(req.session.Client) === 'undefined' || req.session.Client && req.session.Client.name !== req.subdomains[0]) {
            delete req.session.Client;
            client = false;
            return next();
        }
        //if client already has an existing connection make it active
        else if (global.App.clients.indexOf(req.session.Client.name) > -1) {
            global.App.activdb = global.App.clientdbconn[req.session.Client.name]; //global.App.clientdbconnection is an array of or established connections
            console.log('did not make new connection for ' + req.session.Client.name);
            return next();
        }
        //make new db connection
        else {
            console.log('setting db for client ' + req.subdomains[0] + ' and ' + req.session.Client.dbUrl);
            client = mongoose.createConnection(req.session.Client.dbUrl /*, dbconfigoptions*/);
            client.on('connected', function () {
                console.log('Mongoose default connection open to  ' + req.session.Client.name);
                //If pool has not been created, create it and Add new connection to the pool and set it as active connection
                if (typeof(global.App.clients) === 'undefined' || typeof(global.App.clients[req.session.Client.name]) === 'undefined' && typeof(global.App.clientdbconn[req.session.Client.name]) === 'undefined') {
                    clientname = req.session.Client.name;
                    global.App.clients.push(req.session.Client.name);// Store name of client in the global clients array
                    activedb = global.App.clientdbconn[clientname] = client; //Store connection in the global connection array and set it as the current active database
                    console.log('I am now in the list of active clients  ' + global.App.clients[clientname]);
                    global.App.activdb = activedb;
                    console.log('client connection established, and saved ' + req.session.Client.name);
                    return next();
                }
            });
            // When the connection is disconnected
            client.on('disconnected', function () {
                console.log('Mongoose ' + req.session.Client.name + ' connection disconnected');
            });

            // If the Node process ends, close the Mongoose connection
            process.on('SIGINT', function () {
                client.close(function () {
                    console.log(req.session.Client.name + ' connection disconnected through app termination');
                    process.exit(0);
                });
            });
        }


    }
}

module.exports = setclientdb;
```

### Further Explanations Coming

Comment: need that further explanation :(

Comment: Is there a benefit to creating client connections on demand rather than just connecting to all client DBs on app initialisation and then using the connection when required? Can the connection be dropped? I suppose if MongoDB goes down then the connection will be dropped.. then if it came back up the app would need to be restarted. Your method solves that problem - I think I answered my own question.