# How to change a MongoDB schema on request

Tags: node.js, mongoose, meanjs

I'm about to develop an application in MEANJS. Now I think it would be a nice thing to change the mongodb connection, at least the schema, programatically.

The reason why I'm thinking about this is, so I can have seperate and different data, by driving the same application code.

I read the API documentation for mongoose, but didn't find anything about this.

Has anyone done this or something similar, or has a better suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Markus

Comment: "separate and different data, by driving the same application code". Can you maybe give an example on how you want to change the schema ?

Comment: Well lets say, to write an application for different companies. Everything is hosted centralized. So the need is by law, to seperate all the data to different databases, or at least schemas.

Comment: I recently found this here, which sounds promising. I will give it a try. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588253/dynamic-database-connection-to-mongodb-or-mongoose-from-nodejs