# Multi Tenant Application NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, saas

I am trying to build a multi tenant system where a code will be given to the user and then based on the code further interaction will take place with the respective database.

I looked into the following approach https://github.com/asimzsaeed/mongodb_node_multi_tenancy_startup but it has set up multiple domains and then change the global connection.

My requirement is to have a single website and then play with the db connection with the session of the user.

For example

User 1 logs in then he is assigned DB1
User 2 logs in then he is assigned DB2
User 3 logs in then he is assigned DB1 because User1 and User3 has same code.

So I want to learn how can I manage such a situation in NodeJS and MongoDB app.

Please suggest any article to read where such situation is handled. Looking forward to a positive response.

Comment: can you answer your own question now ?

Comment: Hi @ChiKaLiO You can refer to this for dynamic connection as this is what I have done to achieve the same.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/31766926/2159510

Comment: can you share your app.js & config.js files ?